# Broken code in company contact form

Tags: php, forms

The contact form on my employer's website doesn't work so they asked me to fix it. I examined the code and found some issues. The "form method" was incorrect so I changed that. Also, the email address in the send_form_email.php was wrong so I fixed that as well but the form still doesn't work. Can anybody see what I'm missing here?

```
    <form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" class="fieldbox2">
      <table width="344" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="169" align="right" valign="middle"><span class="fieldbox1">
            <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="First Name"/>
          </span></td>
          <td width="7" align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="168" align="left" valign="middle"><span class="fieldbox1">
            <input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" value="Last Name"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle"><span class="fieldbox1">
            <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="Email"/>
          </span></td>
          <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span class="fieldbox1">
            <input name="city" type="text"  id="city" value="City"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle"><span class="fieldbox1">
            <input name="telephone" type="text"  id="telephone" value="Phone Number"/>
          </span></td>
          <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><span class="fieldbox1">
            <input name="company" type="text"  id="company" value="Company"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><textarea name="textarea2" cols="45" id="textarea2">Write Comments</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><p>
            <input name="sendbutton" type="button" id="sendbutton" value="Submit Query"/>
          </p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


    $email_to = "#";
    $email_subject = "Quote Requested";


    function died($error) {

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['city']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['company']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $city = $_POST['city']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['phone_number']; // not required
    $company = $_POST['company']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$city)) {
    $error_message .= 'The City you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>


Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in what way?

Comment: Well, what doesn't work exactly? “but the form still doesn't work." is pretty vague.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Nothing happens when the submit button is clicked. I didn't write this code. I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: The problem is that we don't have anything to go on with this. There can be a number of reasons why your code isn't working. The most obvious one is that you're using a normal button instead of submit button on the form. Therefor it probably never gets submitted. But it can also be that you're using a private mailserver and therefor the mail is being blocked. The code could be working perfectly fine without you knowing it. Then again it might be some issues with your regex or `isset()`. There's just to much "guessing" for us.

Comment: All in all there's quite a lot "wrong" with your code. You are using HTML to design instead of CSS. You're using regex where you should use filter vars. You're using `isset()` where you should use `empty()`. The entire code should be reworked if you want my honest opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i can see in your code you require comments as an input, but i could not find any input named 'comments'. This is probably the issue you are facing. you named the comments input 'textarea2
'

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed it!